Integrating NATS with AWS IoT core
Is there any method to stream data from AWS IoT core to NATS?
I need to stream data from AWS IoT core to services like kinesis in other accounts.The cross account data transfer is available only for limited AWS services. So I would like to try NATS.Is this possible?
I'm also open to other solutions to make cross account data streaming from AWS IoT core.
